# Concatenate Columns as Index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing a text file into pandas, and would like to concatenate 3 of the columns from the file to make the index.

I am open to doing this in 1 or more steps.  I can either do the conversion at the same time I create the DataFrame, or I can create the DataFrame and restructure it with the newly created column.  Knowing how to do this both ways would be the most helpful for me.

I would eventually like the index to be value of concatenating the values in the first 3 columns.

Comment: What do you mean with 'concatenating the values'? Are it strings you want to concatenate? Or do you want a multi-index?

Comment: A multi-index won't work.  I am just trying to concatenate 3 strings.  Each one is in a seperate DataFrame field.

Comment: it would help if you post the data (or at least part of it), and your code so far

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your columns consist of strings, you can just use the `+` operator (addition in the context of strings is to concatenate them in python, and pandas follows this):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'year':['2012', '2012'], 'month':['01', '02']})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
  month  year
0    01  2012
1    02  2012

In [4]: df['concatenated'] = df['year'] + df['month']

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
  month  year concatenated
0    01  2012       201201
1    02  2012       201202
```

And then, if this column is created, you can just use `set_index` to change the index

```
In [6]: df = df.set_index('concatenated')

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
             month  year
concatenated
201201          01  2012
201202          02  2012
```

---

Note that `pd.concat` is not to 'concat'enate strings but to concatenate series/dataframes, so to add columns or rows of different dataframes or series together into one dataframe (not several rows/columns into one row/column). See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html for an extensive explanation of this.

Comment: If the month and year data was integers, you could concatenate with: `df['concatenated'] = df['year'].apply(str) + df['month'].apply(str)`

Comment: How do I reverse the process?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `read_csv` to import your text file, there is an `index_col` argument that you can [pass a list of column names or numbers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#reading-an-index-with-a-multiindex) to. This will end up creating a `MultiIndex` - I'm not sure if that suits your application.

If you want to explicitly concatenate your index together (assuming that they are strings), it seems you can do so with the `+` operator. (Warning, untested code ahead)

```
df['concatenated'] = df['year'] + df['month']
df.set_index('concatenated')
```

Comment: Sounds logical, but when I try it I get a "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" error.  Is there something I am missing?  The DataFrame has the default Auto Incrementing index, so I know it unique.

Comment: @DJElbow: Seems like the set of concatenated fields has duplicates. An index has to be unique.

Comment: Just to clarify - I am getting this error before resetting the index.  This is the test code I am using that is throwing the error: visits['concatenated'] = pd.concat([visits['year'],visits['month']])

Comment: @DJElbow: Maybe try `pd.concat([visits['year'], visits['month']]).reindex_like(visits)`?

Comment: This gives me the same error -> d.concat([visits['year'], visits['month']]).reindex_like(visits)

Comment: @DJElbow: So the error is occurring when you call `pd.concat` (as opposed to when you assign to df["concatenated"])?

Comment: Actually this, pd.concat([visits2['year'], visits2['month']]), does seem to be working somewhat.  But it appears that it is concatenating the month as rows beneath year.  When I use axis=1 it appears to remain as 2 fields instead of 1.